# Creating input elements and filling them with js script

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to add some rows of input to my form so I will be able to post them to the back-end in one request, and also be able to add more of the same information type if need be
this is the code that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input id="firstElement" type="text" name="firstElement" value="">
    <button onClick="addRow()">add row</button><br>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    function addRow() {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var myElement1 = document.getElementById("firstElement").value;

        document.getElementById("firstElement").value = "";

        var i = 0;

        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        input1.type = "text";
        input1.name= "myElement1"+ i;
        input1.disabled = "true";
        input1.value = myElement1;
        container.appendChild(input1);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        i++;
        }
  </script>
</body>
```

this code shows the output for a second or less and then nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `type` attribute of a button element is `submit`, so when you click the button you're actually submitting your form. Change that easily by specifying the `type` to be a `button` instead:

```
<button onClick="addRow()" type="button">add row</button>
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2vj4mff9/)**

Comment: Another option, while not as nice, is to add `return false;` in the `onClick` event.